# Gnomonic projection into 2-dim ndarray with healpy

Tags: python, numpy, astronomy, healpy

Gnomview allows to visualize the gnomonic projection of a spherical map. How can I store the projection in a 2-dimensional numpy.ndarray? What's the healpy's equivalent of the `map_out` option of IDL's gnomview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was not supported in `healpy`, so I implemented it,
you can check the development version of `healpy` from the github repository, then:

```
In [14]: hp.gnomview(np.arange(12), return_projected_map=True)
Out[14]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[ 4.  4.  4. ...,  4.  4.  4.]
 [ 4.  4.  4. ...,  4.  4.  4.]
 [ 4.  4.  4. ...,  4.  4.  4.]
 ..., 
 [ 4.  4.  4. ...,  4.  4.  4.]
 [ 4.  4.  4. ...,  4.  4.  4.]
 [ 4.  4.  4. ...,  4.  4.  4.]],
         mask = False,
   fill_value = -1.6375e+30)
```

the returned projected map is a 2d masked numpy array.
This will be available in the next `healpy` version.

Comment: Sorry, but I have not understood. How can I use this option? Helpy tells me: gnomview() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_projected_map'

Comment: But is there any way get that projection with healpy? Maybe with `projmap` of GnomonicProj? I tried but I cannot use that function and the documentation is of little help

Comment: I added this to the development version of `healpy`, just download it:  https://github.com/healpy/healpy/archive/master.zip, unzip, cd into the folder and run `python setup.py install` (with sudo if necessary)

Comment: hi, I wrote more detailed instructions on how to build the development version on github: https://github.com/healpy/healpy/issues/105#issuecomment-17485534

Comment: Although the thread is already a bit old - is there also a function included to write the projected map into a FITS file, or do I have to write that on my own, e.g. using AstroPy? If it is included, I did not find it... thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there is not, you can use either astropy or h5py or cPickle